# 3-D Realization of Symmetries of a Tetrahedron

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

We know that the total symmetry group of tetrahedron is $S_4$. I tried to realize these 24 symmetries, but failed to ''realize'' six of them, which correspond to the $4$-cycles $(a \,b\,c\,d)$ (being permutations of vertices).

**Question:** What is an easiest way to "realize" these six symmetries in 3-space, which common undergraduates can understand.

Comment: How can you fail to realize $6$ of them? The symmetries you realize form a subgroup, if its size is greater than $12$, it's the whole group.

Comment: 12 symmetries are rotations; next 6 are reflections; I didn't understand remaining 6. (Slight correction after your comment is done)

Answer (score 4):

The other six are neither reflections nor rotations.  They reverse handedness, so they need a reflection.
Take two edges - 13 and 24.  Take their midpoints 1A3 and 2B4.  Draw an axis between A and B.  Rotate 90 degrees about AB, then reflect in the plane that perpendicularly bisects AB.

Comment: One can think of this as the extension to $\mathbb{R}^3$ of a glide reflector on the circumscribed 2-sphere of the tetrahedron. Ordinarily, as on the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glide_reflection, one thinks of glide reflections along lines in the Euclidean plane. But glide reflections along great circles in a 2-sphere work out pretty much the same way. In the construction of @Michael, the great circle at issue is the intersection of the circumscribed 2-sphere and the reflection plane that perpendicularly bisects AB.